# Is there any faster way to get word embeddings given sub-word embeddings in BERT

Tags: pytorch, tokenize, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, word-embedding

Using bert.tokenizer I can get the subword ids and the word spans of words in a sentence, for example, given the sentence "This is an example", I get the encoded_text embeddings of ["th","##is","an","exam","##ple"],and the word_spans list: [[0,2],[2,3],[3,5]]
My implements is

```
word_embeddings = torch.rand(len(word_spans),768).to(torch.device('cuda'))
for seq,word in enumerate(word_spans):
    word_embeddings[seq,:] = torch.mean(encoded_text[word[0]:word[1],:],0,True)
```

is there any faster way  to combine the vectors of all subwords of the same word  in pytorch?

Answer (score 0):

I use the  [Flair](https://github.com/flairNLP/flair)  library and it solves my problems